# C# Action parameters in extension methods

Tags: c#

I'm using DevExpress to build up grids, but I'm trying to build helper methods to simplify the amount of code to generate.  For instance, the following simple example produces a grid column:

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "StatusId";
    column.Caption = "Status";
    column.Width = Unit.Percentage(20);
});
```

I want to use extension methods to get the following, which allows the developer to simplify the basic work but still get access to the advanced settings:

```
settings.AddColumn("StatusId", "Status", column =>
{
    column.Width = Unit.Percentage(20);
});
```

I could just return a column variable, but that means having to create a new variable name for each column, which is why I wanted to maintain the Action approach.

What would my extension method look like to support this format?  It would need to create the column with the default settings applied, and add it to the columns collection.  This is as far as I get:

```
public static void AddColumn(this GridViewSettings settings, string fieldName, string caption, Action<MVCxGridViewColumn> column)
{
    //...?
}
```

Comment: In order for you code to work the code inside must call back the column Action.  This means you have to have it contain an MVCxGridViewColumn.  I don't know what that is but you do.  What specific problem are you having?  Do you not know how to create or get an instance of MVCxGridviewColumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  I would make the action parameter optional, so that the developer could leave it out unless they needed it.

```
public static void AddColumn(this GridViewSettings settings, string fieldName, string caption, Action<MVCxGridViewColumn> additionalConfig = null)
{
    var column = new MVCxGridViewColumn
    {
        FieldName = fieldName,
        Caption = caption
    };

    if (additionalConfig != null)
    {
        additionalConfig(column);
    }

    settings.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Call it with

```
settings.AddColumn("StatusId", "Status", column =>
{
    column.Width = 20;
});
```

or

```
settings.AddColumn("StatusId", "Status");
```

Comment: I like the optional usage and the better naming of the parameter

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void AddColumn(
    this GridViewSettings settings, 
    string fieldName, 
    string caption, 
    Action<MVCxGridViewColumn> action
)
{
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = fieldName;
        column.Caption = caption;
        action(column);
    });
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry it should be `action(column);` of course, answer updated.